# Telerik RadGrid SelectionChanging Event Leaving Partial Selected Row

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, telerik-grid

I am more of a web developer, but I was recently asked to look at a WinForms application.

What I have is a Telerik WinForms RadGridView. When I click on a row, and the SelectionChange event is fired.

Within this event, pop-up a quick MessageBox to display a Yes/No confirmation if the data in the row has changed.

This is working using the following code:

[image]

So when the line

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

is executed, it acts as

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

in javascript.

The unfortunate issue that I have, is when the screen renders, the newly selected row is still highlighted and I do know how to stop this.

[image]

I have looked at the RadGridView object model and found IsActive and IsSelected attributes, but nothing appears to stop this from happening.

Looking at the image, The row with the blue bar was selected, then on selecting the cell above, showing the cell in blue and the row with a blue border. I clicked on the cancel option which passed a DialogResult.Cancel back from the warning message.

This executed the line

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

What do I need to do, to lose the blue border and blue cell colour from the selected row?

Comment: Any chance you can past the code you screen grabbed - as dialogresult.cancel needs cancel but its not clear that this is the only message option.. is it actually excuting the e.cancel line? as this should be kicking in before the actual selection takes place

Comment: this is the complete delegate called when a user changes the selection within the grid. e.Cancel = true IS called.

Comment: thanks but the code is not complete : "You have unsaved  ????" it goes off screen as do other lines

Comment: It is complete bar the ShowMessage parameters which are not relevent or required for this question.

Comment: It is if I wish to try and recreate it - I want to be sure that your dialog is generating the cancel to call e.cancel - this is not a minimal viable example.  There isnt enough code to test it.

Comment: I'd suggest using the RowValidating event in this case.  You should be able to move this code to that event and get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you all for your help jaredbaszler